# bootstrap-select me devuelve el text pegado de lo que se selecciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

tengo una duda..
Estoy trabajando con bootstrap-select por primera vez, al seleccionar mas de una opcion en pantalla me los muestra separados por coma, por ejemplo:
UNO, DOS, TRES, CUARTO
y al obtener el valor desde el archivo js con el comando 
$("#combobox option:selected").text();  me devuelve el valor UNODOSTRESCUATRO, como puedo obtenerlo al igual como me lo muestra en pantalla?

Este es el codigo del select:

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple name="combobox " id="combobox " >
                        <option value="1">UNO</option>
                        <option value="2">DOS</option>
                        <option value="3">TRES</option>
                        <option value="4">CUATRO</option>

                    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar la función **[change](https://api.jquery.com/change/)** de JQuery para eso, de esta forma:

```
$('.selectpicker').on('change', function(){
   var selected = []
   selected = $(this).val()
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
  $('.selectpicker').on('change', function(){
    var selected = []
    selected = $(this).val()
    alert(selected);
  })
})
```

```css
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
display: block;
margin: 0px;
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container mt-2">
  <select class="selectpicker" multiple>
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si haces `$('#combobox').val()` te va a devolver un vector con cada value de cada option seleccionado, pero si lo que necesitas son los textos de los ítems seleccionados podrías utilizar el map de jQuery para recorrerlos y obtener su texto, y después juntar todo con un join.

Acá te dejo un ejemplo que podés ejecutar y verlo.

¡Suerte!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" multiple name="combobox" id="combobox">
  <option value="1">UNO</option>
  <option value="2">DOS</option>
  <option value="3">TRES</option>
  <option value="4">CUATRO</option>
</select>
<br/>
<button onclick="verValor()">Prueba</button>
<script>
  function verValor() {
    var valores = $.map(
      $('#combobox option:selected'),
      function(o, i) { return $(o).text(); });
    alert(valores.join(', '));
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Y si esos valores que me regresas en el vector los necesito para hacer un filtrado desde sql, sabes de que manera podría utilizarlo?
ejemplo: select * from table where numero in vector?

Comment: Depende el lenguaje que estés utilizando en el servidor. Te recomiendo abrir otra pregunta con esta consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Tambien puedes poner la funcion onchange en el elemento:

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple name="combobox " id="combobox " onchange="myfunction(this.value)" >
                    <option value="1">UNO</option>
                    <option value="2">DOS</option>
                    <option value="3">TRES</option>
                    <option value="4">CUATRO</option>

                </select>
           <script>
                function myfunction(val){
                    console.log(val);
                }
            </script>
```